# How do I prevent a memory card from mounting as read-only in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sd-card, fsck

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 and when I try to mount an SD card with the GUI I have to type `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/disk` before I can write anything to the card. Is there a hidden setting to make it mount read-write?

Comment: We could use some diagnostic information. Under System->Administration, there's an application to view the system logs. Watch /var/log/syslog while you insert the card and see if anything comes up. Also, open up Places->Computer, and right-click on your SD card and select Properties. Go to the Volume tab and tell us what filesystem the SD card is.

Comment: It's FAT32 for compatibility with a Sansa Fuze. It looks like my first solution was correct, but I had corrupted the filesystem again by removing the card too soon. I will think about replacing the card, maybe it has some bad blocks.

Comment: This question, in fact, was the answer to my problem. Hail `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/disk`. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran `sudo fsck -a ...` on the offending device. After fixing the file system corruption it mounts read-write. I had the problem again, and fixed it again with fsck. Will have to be more careful about always ejecting properly.

Answer (score 1):

i was just looking for this as an eee pc specific problem and came across [this](http://wiki.eeeuser.com/howto:sd_permissions):

Open terminal.

type in

```
cd ..
```

until you are at your file system level, ie your cd .. just returns to where you are at.

Type in

```
cd /media
```

Type in

```
ls -l
```

to see if your disk is there, usually labeled as disk. You will see something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2008-01-20 09:53 disk
```

Now you will need to change premissions,

Type in

```
sudo su
```

and your password. Type in

```
chown <your user name> <disk name>
```

ie:

```
chown user disk
```

Now type in

```
ls -l
```

and you should see the change.

ie: drwxr-xr-x 3 user root 4096 2008-01-20 09:53 disk

Comment: In my case, the media was mounted read-only, so not even root could write to it. Modern distributions provide a gui to mount removable media in which case it will be writable by the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the write protection hard-switch on the sd-card reader adapter? That was the problem for me.